# Can we replace the antipodal map with an arbitrary continuous map in the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$   $\newcommand{\bd}{\text{Bd}}$

> **Question.**
> Let $f:S^n\to \R^n$ and $g:S^n\to S^n$ be continuous functions.
> Is it necessarily true that there is an $x\in S^n$ such that $f(x) = f(g(x))$?

The conclusion is true if $n=1$ and an easy proof can be given.
Also, the Borsuk-Ulam theorem states that the statement is true if $g$ is the antipodal map.

However, I am struggling to prove (or disprove) the statement if $n=2$.
To start with I chose $f:S^2\to \R^2$ as the "squishing map."
More precisely, $$f(x, y, z) = (x, y)$$
for all $(x, y, z) \in S^2$.

I tried to construct a $g:S^2\to S^2$ for which there is no $x\in S^2$ such that $f(x) = f(g(x))$.
Even here I have not been able to answer the question one way or the other.

My intuition is that the statement should be false for $n\geq 2$ but I am stuck.

Comment: Cf. https://mathoverflow.net/q/61141